# How to set trial period in shopify app?

Tags: shopify, recurring-billing, time-trial

I have created shopify app and setting up billing Api. In the App, I want to apply trial period of 20 days. I have created the charge during the app installation and send customers to confirmation url so that they can accept or decline the charge.. So I want to know that if customer decline the payment charge, then can he uses the app featurs till trial period?

Answer (score 0):

If a customer declines the subscription, you still get the confirmation URL callback. Examine the charge. The status will say declined. At this point you can kill off their DB token and destroy their session. This will ensure they cannot use your App as they declined the terms.

It is one bad aspect of the whole billing scenario. I have lots of customers that are faced with a question they don't read. So they assume the trial you offer for free is activated by declining the subscription. Silly customers... still cannot operate the Internet :)

Comment: so they will only get free trial if they accept the payment.right?

Comment: please reply as I am waiting for your reply

Comment: right.. as without accepting a subscription, there is nothing they should be doing using your App.

Comment: I have created an shopify App and setting up recurring billing using Api. But now, I am confused about one thing i.e when to create charge and send confirmation url to customer so that he can accept/decline 1) On installing app 2) After 20 days as I also have 20 days trial facility mentioned in the app. I have checked by installing other paid app and they not ask for accepting payment during installation (example app also having 7 days trial). Please let me know the best approach. Thanks

Comment: please reply as you are my only hope

Comment: If a paying App installed without asking you for payment, then they are doing it wrong,